# Unix Background Jobs under SSH

Tags: linux, process, ssh, amazon-ec2, background-process

I have an Linux instance running on EC2 which I I ran some server on (some server I wrote). I ran it as a background job and logged out of SSH.

When logging back in, I cannot find the job when typing 'jobs'. The only way to terminate it is to find the PID of the process that the port is running under by using: `lsof -i :port` and then killing it: `kill -9 PID`.

Is there anyway where I can actually SSH back in and find it running under `jobs`? Why is the process disappearing when changing sessions?

I always use GNU Screen, and when using Screen the process still shows up. I'm just wondering why it 'disappears' when not running screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jobs` only applies to the shell that started the job.

You should look into `screen` or `tmux` (or `byobu` as wrapper for both).

They allow you to start a shell session which can be detached when you log out and reattached when you come back...

Comment: Yeah I use Screen religiously. It didn't occur to me though that the shell session that started the job died. Thanks!